# JS - if/else - addClass. Button

Tags: jquery

Что не так в моем скрипте ?

```
<script>
if($('body:contains(".light")'))
    $(".zrlight").addClass("active");
else
    $(".zrdark").addClass("active");
    $(".zrlight").remove("active");
</script>
```

Когда в body class="light"
То кнопка light активна как и нужно, но переключаясь на dark все равно active кнопка light.
Я что то делаю не так? Совершенно не знаю js.
Пробовал уже и так и сяк и с помощью else if, все равно горит кнопка не та либо обе.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if($('body').hasClass('light')) {
  $(".zrdark").removeClass("active");
  $(".zrlight").addClass("active");
} else {
  $(".zrdark").addClass("active");
  $(".zrlight").removeClass("active");
}
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо ! Помогло

Comment: @zeroroot Пожалуйста. Успехов. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.

Answer (score 0):

скорее всего надо так

```
if ($('body').hasClass('light'))
```

и

```
if ($('body').hasClass('dark'))
```

то есть дословно `hasClass` - есть ли класс. В скобках - название класса.

---

https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/

[http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/Наличие_класса](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0)

Comment: Спасибо ! Ваш ответ так же верное решение